# De Rham Cohomology groups of $\mathbb{R}^3\times S^3$

Tags: algebraic-topology, symplectic-geometry

I am doing a topology class and in the exercises, I encountered the question to Calculate de Rham cohomology groups of $\mathbb{R}^3\times S^3$. I thought of using the Künneth formula, when I got to $H^2$ I encountered something interesting.  By Künneth formula
\begin{eqnarray}
H^2(\mathbb{R}^3\times S^3)&=& \left(H^2(\mathbb{R}^3)\otimes H^0(S^3)\right) \oplus \left(H^1(\mathbb{R}^3) \otimes H^1(S^3)\right) \\
&\oplus& \left(H^0(\mathbb{R}^3)\otimes H^2(S^3)\right) \\
&=& 0, 
\end{eqnarray}
but I discovered that this is a symplectic manifold, so $H^2 =0$ can not happen.

I don`t see where am I wrong. If someone could help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Random point: are you sure that $H^2=0$ isn’t impossible only for *compact* symplectic manifolds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is correct to say that that 1) your manifold has zero second cohomology (it's homotopy equivalent to $S^3$) and 2) your manifold has a symplectic structure (it's diffeomorphic to the cotangent bundle of $S^3$, because $S^3$ is parallelizable).

But only closed symplectic manifolds are required to have nonzero second cohomology! The general fact is that, if $\omega$ is a symplectic form on a $2n$-dimensional manifold, then $\omega^n$ is a volume form. If the manifold is closed, than any volume form must represent a nonzero cohomology class, and so $\omega$ must also represent a nonzero cohomology class. But if the manifold is not closed, then $H^{2n}$ is trivial anyway, so nothing more can be concluded.